# How to get syntax declarations to be used by case splitting

Tags: emacs, agda

I would like to automatically case over arguments using a syntax declared
besides the one given as a type constructor. For example,

```
postulate P : ℕ → ℕ → Set

data Silly : Set where
  goo : (n : ℕ) → Fin n → (m : ℕ) → Fin m → P n m → Silly
```

Here, I'd like to have the proof `P n m` occur between the `n` and `m` arguments, but that cannot be since both need to be declare for it to be expressed. Hence, we use a syntax declaration:

```
syntax goo n i m j pf = i ⟵[ n , pf , m ]⟶ j
```

Now, we can write-up by-hand

```
want-to-use-syntax-in-pattern-matching : Silly → Set
want-to-use-syntax-in-pattern-matching (i ⟵[ n , pf , m ]⟶ j) = ℕ
```

This works fine, but when I case-split via `C-c C-c`, it uses `goo` instead of my syntax. Is there any way to make case splitting use my declared syntax ?

( 
Incidentally, using

```
syntax goo n i m j pf = i ─[ n , pf , m ]⟶ j
```

fails, where `─` is produced by `\---`

)

Comment: The version using `\---` works with Agda 2.4.2.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowadays Agda resugars patterns on the left if they are in scope unqualified
so this would just work.

Comment: An example or link demonstrating an example would be helpful for people who land at this page ;-)